# stop form process with ajax if input value is empty

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

My ajax code below will stop the form pprocess if an input value is empty, then showing an popup alert. The problem is, the process will continue after the alert popup closed. How can i stop the process until the input value is not empty?

```
$("#spdf-form").on('submit', function () {

var title = $('#spdf-form input[name="title"]').val();
var url = $('#spdf-form input[name="pdf"]').val();

if (title == "" || url == "") {
        alert('Error; title or url is missing.');
    return false;
}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#spdf-form").on('submit', function (e) {

    var title = $('#spdf-form input[name="title"]').val();
    var url = $('#spdf-form input[name="pdf"]').val();

    if (title == "" || url == "") {
        alert('Error; title or url is missing.');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle demonstrating this concept: http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/4UNEg/

Comment: ^ That is an awesome way to do that, never thought of that. EDIT: Except that wouldn't you have to use == instead of ===? false === anything + anything is always false

Comment: wow, it's works, thanks. But i have another problem because i have another ajax to this process, it's causing my form still continued the process. how can i stop another ajax function until the first function is true?

Comment: Just call another ajax when it's true. Move validation into another function and validate form before doing something.